# MERN App - React state in Render - TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

So, I’ve built the component Post for a forum. It is supposed to show the respective post and fill it with data according to its id. The file makes a get request via axios to mongodb, loads in all of the posts and the filters them according to the right id (which I get from the url).
Then, in componentWillMount, I

```
console.log(this.state.idUrl[0].username)
```

this.state.idUrl is basically an array. And since it always only has one object in it (which contains content for the respective post, with username, content, header, etc.), I feel comfortable using the 0 index. And the whole thing works fine, it shows me the username for the right post.
Now, I want to access this.state.idUrl[0] in render. But it only says “cannot read property ‘username’ of undefined". Does anyone know why that is?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'


class Post extends Component {
    constructor(props)  {
        super(props)
        this.state={
            idUrl: "",
            
           
        }
 
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        let url = window.location.pathname
        var lastPartUrl = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        //console.log(lastPartUrl);
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/posts/all')
        .then(response => {
          

          let rightPost = response.data.filter(post => post._id === lastPartUrl)
         
          this.setState({idUrl: rightPost})    
          //why does this work but ...
          console.log(this.state.idUrl[0].username)    
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div> 
                {/*... but this won't? */}

               <h1>{this.state.idUrl[0].username}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Post
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the request in axios takes long time thus this `{this.state.idUrl[0].username}` is not defined.

Try something like:

`{this.state.idUrl && this.state.idUrl[0] && this.state.idUrl[0].username}`

---

In addition, since you know isUrl is an array, I would suggest defining it as as array:

```
this.state={
    idUrl: [],
}
```

So you can do:`{this.state.idUrl.length > 0 && this.state.idUrl[0].username}`

Comment: I figured it had something to do with the code being asynchronous. But I didn't know how to adapt it accordingly. Your solution worked though, thanks :)

Comment: If you think my solution is the right one, please confirm it by clicking the check icon on my post. Thanks